# what does "dating 101" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> It’s email dating 101: there’s nothing worse than waking up, checking your email, and find that annoying email from last night – trying to get back into your inbox for a second round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In universities, courses in a subject are generally labeled with numerical codes to quickly distinguish between them without needing to use the full course name and to indicate the order in which courses should be taken. In American universities (maybe elsewhere too, I can only speak for America), the first course you take in a subject will often be given the code 101 (for example, English 101, Literature 101, Mathematics 101).

This has developed into an idiom, "{topic} 101", that simply means "the basics of {topic}". So in your example, "It's email dating 101" roughly translates to "It's the basics of email dating". Put another way, you might translate it as "This is one of the first things you need to learn about email dating".

Comment: It is indeed largely a US thing, though it's sometimes found outside of the US as much because the figurative use has spread outside its borders as for any other reason.